# Retrieve data from controllers and show in views - Yii2-Basic-App

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In my form, I'm having 8-9 fileds. In which all are hard-coded, Except one, which should come from database.

**UsersControllers.php** (controller)

```
public function actionRegister() 
{
    .
    .
    model = new Users();
    $modelUserType=UserType::find()->select(['id', 'type'])->where(['status' => 1])->all();
        return $this->render('register', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelUserType'=>$modelUserType,
            'module' => $this->module,
      ]);
}
```

Values are coming if i do `print_r($modelUserType);`

But, i don't know to show all those "UserType" table values in views for radio button.

```
<?=
    $form->field($modelUserType, 'user_type')
    ->radioList(array('1' => 'An Individual', '2' => 'Firm')) // Here.
    ->label('Are You')
?>
```

**register.php** (view)

```
.
.

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->label('Password') ?> 
<?= $form->field($model, 'confirm_password')->passwordInput()->label('Confirm Password') ?>

<?=
    $form->field($model, 'user_type')
    ->radioList(array('1' => 'An Individual', '2' => 'Firm'))
    ->label('Are You')
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textInput() ?>
.
.
```

I'm not getting any tutorials or I am not able to find the correct tutorials for it. 
Little help needed. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function actionRegister()
    {    
        $model = new Users();
        .
        .
        $modelUserType=UserType::find()->select(['id', 'type'])->where(['status' => 1])->asArray()->all();
    $type=[];
    foreach($modelUserType as $k=>$v){
                   if(is_array($v))$type[$v["id"]]=$v["type"];

    }


 return $this->render('register', [
          'model' => $model,
          'type'=>$type,
          'module' => $this->module,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Nuriddin. Answer came but in different way. Its showing 'id' in place of 'type'. User should see 'type' instead of 'id'.

Comment: <label>
<input name="Users[user_type]" value="1" type="radio"> 1
</label>

Comment: value="1". Ok. Fine. But, 'type' should come with respect to its ID in label Mr @Nuriddin.

Comment: yeah ok, can you check this array retrieved from database with var_dump or print_r  it should be array 2d

Comment: on var_dump. i got. array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
}

Comment: i think in your databse table usertype column type is not string. am i right.

Comment: No Nuriddin. It's varchar(45). column name is 'type'

Comment: $modelUserType=UserType::find()->select([' 'type','id'])->where(['status' => 1])->indexBy("id")->asArray()->all();  can u use this code

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ERROR

Comment: Okey, just example you my hardcode way, but i m not sure working is it:

Comment: I didn't get it Nuriddin.

Comment: I just post it like answer one minut

Comment: i change my answer and when render view instead of $modelUserType you send $type variable, you can check out.

Comment: Nope. No Problem Nuriddin. You helped me lot. Atleast you gave me more than half answer. I will ask this question again tomorrow. Thanku.

Comment: Yeah Nop, my hardcode was wrong logic when generate array for radiolist. I just fix it and test it

Comment: Undefined variable: type Error coming.

Comment: i change on view sended variable name $modelUserType to $view that way u got this error

Comment: I checked it. But, not fixing. Let me ask one more question with your answer. I'm just embarrass. You helped in many way.

Comment: i'm trying to help you. and others help me like this.

Comment: i'm just new in stackoverflow. is it work now. U must change variable name when render view file form "modelUserType" to "type" or   $form->field($model, 'user_type')
    ->radioList($type)// instead of $type u may use $modelUserType
    ->label('Are You')

Comment: You are a very good person. I appreciate your commendable effort.

Comment: Thanks ;). But we not yet solved your problem. am i right. ;(

Comment: I just asked new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221404/radio-button-yii2-basic-app with your help. Now, let us check, what is the alternative. I thanku very much.

Comment: Hey Nuriddin. Paste that answer here too. Edit your answer with the answer you gave now.

Comment: Thanks ;))))))). Mr Partykar

Comment: You don't thanks to me. You deserve. Be in touch bro. God bless You. :) :)