# Radio Button - Yii2-Basic-App

Tags: php, radio-button, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In radio button, value is coming. But, I want to display the name of that value.

my **user_types** (table)

```
id            type              status           created_at
1           An Individual       1                   2015
2           Firm                1                   2015
```

**UserController.php** (controller)

```
public function actionRegister()
{    
    $model = new Users();
    .
    .
    $modelUserType=UserType::find()->select(['id', 'type'])->where(['status' => 1])
                      ->indexBy("id")->column();
    return $this->render('register', [
          'model' => $model,
          'modelUserType'=>$modelUserType,
          'module' => $this->module,
    ]);

}
```

**register.php** (view)

```
.
.
<?=                        
    $form->field($model, 'user_type')
    ->radioList($type)
    ->label('Are You')       
?>
.
.
```

It's coming like this.
[image]

I want like this
[image]

So any idea how to bring `'type'` column to display instead of `'id'` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr Partykar and now i understand you.This is my answer.This is work to me also for render list of radio buttons. Please, reply this is fix your problem

```
public function actionRegister()
    {    
        $model = new Users();
        .
        .
        $modelUserType=UserType::find()->select(['id', 'type'])->where(['status' => 1])->asArray()->all();
    $type=[];
    foreach($modelUserType as $k=>$v){
                   if(is_array($v))$type[$v["id"]]=$v["type"];

    }

        return $this->render('register', [
              'model' => $model,
              'type'=>$type,
              'module' => $this->module,
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Ha Ha :D Wooaahhh..!! Great Nuriddin. Great One. Thank You So Much. I don't know How to Thank You.

Comment: don't mention it. i'm just happy to help you ;)

Comment: Hey @Nuriddin I asked one question here regarding Yii2. If you are free, can you please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759514/model-save-not-working-in-yii2

Comment: Hi @nuriddin: If i want to select one radio button as selected, then how to do ? This question only.

Comment: Hi there different ways and it's related exact situation. e.g :if you want set selected deafult radio button - you can do this with  setting  value of radio button as default value ['value' => $defaultvalue]. or init user_type prop  in your model : $model->user_type=$defaultvalue;

Comment: Hi @nuriddin: Do you have any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888464/two-different-layouts-for-guest-user-logged-in-user-yii2