# disable a css only for one layout yii2

Tags: css, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to integrate a custom theme on YII2 basic app.

I have two layouts, the main layout and other is login layout.

Now I don't need a css file say xyz.css on login layout but it gets loaded there and my design is getting messed up. Any proper way of disabling it on that one layout?

I am registering my css files from AppAsset.php file.

the css section look like

```
    public $css = [
        'themes/mytheme/assets/css/xyz.css',
        'themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css'
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step - 1:** Create **LoginAsset.php** in `assets` Folder.

**LoginAsset.php**

In this file, Keep those `.css` & `.js` which is required for login.

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class LoginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
    'css/include-your-css-if-any.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
      'js/include-your-js-if-any.js',
    ];
}
```

**Step - 2:** Since, you told that you are having one more layout i.e. `login layout`. So, Use **LoginAsset.php** in your `login layout`, Like:

**login.php** (One out of two layouts i.e. `main/login.php`)

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

use app\assets\LoginAsset;
LoginAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
.
. // Your code
```

**Step - 3:** If even though it didn't worked. Then,

Include

```
<?php
use app\assets\LoginAsset;
LoginAsset::register($this);
.
.
?>
```

on top of your `view` file.

**Related Search**

- [Two Different Layouts For Guest User & Logged In User-Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888464/two-different-layouts-for-guest-user-logged-in-user-yii2?rq=1)

Comment: Always Welcome @hs19 `:)`